# TYPO3 QueryInterface multi dimensional constraints

Tags: typo3

I want to make a `$query->logicalAnd` for each array of `$constraintsOr[$key]`. How to loop through them so I get something like this constructed:

```
       $query->matching($query->logicalAnd(
            $query->logicalOr(...$constraintsOr[1]),
            $query->logicalOr(...$constraintsOr[2]),
            etc.
        ));
```

So for example `$constraintsOr[1]` can have multiple `$query` comparisments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$joinableOrConditions = [];
foreach($constraintsOr AS $orIndex => $subConstraints) {
     $joinableOrConditions[] = $query->logicalOr(...$subConstraints);
}

$query->matching($query->logicalAnd(...$joinableOrConditions);
```

you could also try to use array_map and/or anomyous functions, however my method above is the one that is best readable to me personally :D